# iOS swift Facebook AccountKit Customize

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

I have tried to custom header view of AccountKit but it doesn't show the header view. 
This is how I tried:

```
import Foundation
import AccountKit

class AccountKitUIManager: AKFSkinManager {


@objc override func headerViewForState(state: AKFLoginFlowState) -> UIView? {
    let view = UIView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 50))
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue()
    return view
   }

}
```

and

```
func signInWithPhoneNumber() {
    let inputState = NSUUID().UUIDString
    let vc: AKFViewController = accountKit!.viewControllerForPhoneLoginWithPhoneNumber(nil, state: inputState) as! AKFViewController
    vc.delegate = self
    vc.uiManager = AccountKitUIManager.init(skinType: AKFSkinType.Classic, primaryColor: UIColor.blue(), backgroundImage: UIImage(named: "Login-bg-new"), backgroundTint: AKFBackgroundTint.White, tintIntensity: 0.1)
    vc.whitelistedCountryCodes = ["VN"]


    self.presentViewController(vc as! UIViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

what is wrong? Please help me. Thanks

refer link:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit/ios/customizing

Answer (score 1):

You have to use UILabel for that, if you just want to show space view (view without content) use UILabel with padding.